# Compute the limit: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-x^2\ln\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(x-x^2\ln\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$$
What I did:
$l=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y-\ln(y+1)}{y^2}$, putting $y=\frac{1}{x}$.
The answer seems to be $1/2$ but how do I get to that?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By de l'Hôpital $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y-\ln(y+1)}{y^2} =\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-\frac{1}{y+1}}{2y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{2(y+1)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Taylor:

$$\frac{y-\ln(y+1)}{y^2} = \frac{y - (y-\frac{y^2}{2} + O(y^3))}{y^2}=\frac{1}{2} +O(y) \stackrel{y\rightarrow  0^+}{\longrightarrow} \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor’s expansion

- $\ln\frac{x+1}{x}=\ln (1+1/x)=\frac 1x-\frac12x^2+o(x^{-2})$

then

$$x-x^2\ln\frac{x+1}{x}=\frac12+o(1)\to -\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

Use *Taylor's formula* at order $2$ for the log:$$\ln\frac{x+1}x=\ln\Bigl(1+\frac1x\Bigr)=\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{x^2}\Bigr),$$
so
$$x-x^2\ln\frac{x+1}x=x-x^2\Bigl(\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+o\Bigl(\frac1{x^2}\Bigr)\Bigr)=x-x+\frac12-x^2o\Bigl(\frac1{x^2}\Bigr)=\frac12+o(1)\to\frac12.$$